# How do I check the class of an instance that conforms to a protocol in swift?

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-protocols

I'm trying to check the class of an instance which conforms to a protocol.

I have a protocol.

```
protocol ToolbarProtocol {

  func show()

  func hide()

}
```

I have a class which conforms to that protocol.

```
class GameToolbar: ToolbarProtocol {
...
}
```

I have a manager class I createed to manage my toolbars.

```
class ToolbarManager {
  var existingToolbars: [Game.rotation: Array<ToolbarProtocol>]
}
```

In this manager, I have a function that wants to find the first instance of a specific type of toolbar.

```
func getDebugToolbar() -> ToolbarProtocol? {
    return existingToolbars[.east]?.first(where: { (toolbar: ToolbarProtocol) -> Bool in
      toolbar.isKind(of: GameToolbar.self) //This line causes an error because .isKind is not a member of ToolbarProtocol
    })
  }
```

I can't call `isKind(of)` on `toolbar`, which previously worked when my toolbars were a different kind of class provided by an external library (which I'm trying to remove from my codebase because I want different functionality).

I tried making my protocol extend `AnyObject`, but I think that's implicit anyway, and it had no effect.

How can I check an array of instances which conform to a given protocl, to check for specific class types?

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to attempt to cast it, like

```
if let vc = toolbar as? GameToolbar {}
```

In your case, you might need something like this:

```
func getDebugToolbar() -> ToolbarProtocol? {
    return existingToolbars[.east]?.first(where: { (toolbar: ToolbarProtocol) -> Bool in
      let _ = toolbar as? GameToolbar
    })
  }
```

Comment: Good answer. Doing only this should also suffice: return existingToolbars[.east]?.first as? GameToolbar

Comment: Thank you, first as? GameToolbar would only check the first one in the list wouldn't it? first where { condition } would give you the first matching the condition, so would check each element until it found the match or failed

Comment: Yes, you are right. I assumed another functionality for first where.

Comment: On attempt to build that solution, the suggested fix was to simply do `toolbar is GameToolbar` in stead.

Comment: Documented at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html under checking type.